# Growth trend in time series

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, forecasting, prophet

I'm currently working with a dataset that looks as follows:

[image]

I'm using the prophet model provided by meta to forecast the data and I'm quite unsure about the parameter called 'growth'. Now there are $3$ possible values for this growth param namely linear, logistic and flat. If I understood correctly in my case the growth would be flat as the data isn't increasing or decreasing by the year at all? I would appreciate some insights on this parameter and whether I'm interpreting it correctly.